# In yaml files, can I comment between array items listed with hyphens?

Tags: arrays, yaml, comments

In a `yaml` file, there an `args` array.

I'd like to comment out 2 items in the middle of the array.

```
    args:
      - "run"
      - "deploy"
      - "my-service"
      # - "--min-instances=1"
      # - "--max-instances=3"
      -  "--port=8080"
```

Is this legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not ;)
You can check the following site: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_comments.htm